# Testing improper tags from mobile app

Tags: bug

I've selected a tag from meta.stackexchange but then changed to sci-fi stackexchange.

Reason for posting this: [Changing site that you ask to does not change the underlying site you submit to on mobile app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234179/175002)

Comment: The stackoverflow tag doesn't exist on this site as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Comment: Also, you've got enough rep to create bugs, don't you?

Comment: Tags. I meant tags, not bugs.

Comment: @sqb You shouldn't be able to create tags from the mobile app, and from what i can see clicking on the tag doesn't show any questions.

Comment: Ok, now it exists.

Comment: You should add more detail to the question, like steps to recreate the issue.

Comment: @Pureferret Where does it say you shouldn't be able to create tags from mobile?

Comment: @keen for details see the link I've edited in.